# Multiple Table search using one dropdown filter in datatable

Tags: laravel, filter, datatable, dropdown

I am using laravel and data table here I am using 2 data tables on the same page. Now I need to filter both at the same time using the dropdown. The dropdown filter is located outside my table. one table content revenue another one content Expense for the same account number.

I also want to subtract the total value. is like the 1st value came from 1st table total value, and 2nd value came from 2nd table then its subtract. is it possible?

Here Is My Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" >
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.0/css/dataTables.dateTime.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

      <div class="card">
        <h4 class="text-center mt-3 mb-3"><u>Filter</u></h4>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-dark">Account Number</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                              <div id="account_number"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-dark">From</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="min" name="min" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-dark">To</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="max" name="max" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="buttons"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
      <div class="card">
        <h4 class="text-center mt-3 mb-3"><u>Bank Statement</u></h4>
        <p class="text-center" id="account_number1"></p>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class=" table table-borderless  " style="min-width: 845px">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Account Number</th>
                            <th>BAnk Name</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Expenses</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Amount</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <!-- @foreach (App\Models\BankTransaction::where('type','debit')->get() as $item) -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>35302111502</td>
                                <td>ABC Bank</td>
                                <td>2021-09-07</td>
                                <td>Withdraw</td>
                                <td class="text-center">10000</td>
                            </tr>
                       <!-- @endforeach -->
                       <tr>
                          <td>35302111502</td>
                          <td>ABC Bank</td>
                          <td>2021-09-07</td>
                          <td>Online Payment</td>
                          <td class="text-center">10000</td>
                       </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>35302111502</td>
                          <td>ABC Bank</td>
                          <td>2021-09-07</td>
                          <td>Online Payment</td>
                          <td class="text-center">10000</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>54-0211-15145</td>
                          <td>ANC Bank</td>
                          <td>2021-09-05</td>
                          <td>Card Bill</td>
                          <td class="text-center">6000</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Account Number</th>
                            <th>BAnk Name</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Expenses</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                      
                    </tfoot>


                </table>
                <table class=" table table-borderless " style="min-width: 845px">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Account Number</th>
                            <th>BAnk Name</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Revenues</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Amount</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <!-- @foreach (App\Models\BankTransaction::where('type','credit')->get() as $item) -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>35302111502</td>
                                <td>ABC Bank</td>
                                <td>2021-09-06</td>
                                <td>Account Open</td>
                                <td class="text-center">1000</td>
                            </tr>
                        <!-- @endforeach -->
                      <tr>
                                <td>35302111502</td>
                                <td>ABC Bank</td>
                                <td>2021-09-06</td>
                                <td>Diposit</td>
                                <td class="text-center">10000</td>
                            </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>35302111502</td>
                          <td>ABC Bank</td>
                          <td>2021-09-07</td>
                          <td>Balance Transfer</td>
                          <td class="text-center">10000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>54-0211-15145</td>
                          <td>ANC Bank</td>
                          <td>2021-09-01</td>
                          <td>Account Opening</td>
                          <td class="text-center">1000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>54-0211-15145</td>
                          <td>ANC Bank</td>
                          <td>2021-09-03</td>
                          <td>Diposit</td>
                          <td class="text-center">3000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>54-0211-15145</td>
                          <td>ANC Bank</td>
                          <td>2021-09-05</td>
                          <td>Online Earn</td>
                          <td class="text-center">6000</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Account Number</th>
                            <th>BAnk Name</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th class="text-dark"><h4>Total Revenues</h4></th>
                            <th class="text-dark text-center h4"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>


                </table>
                

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
  
  
  
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Date Filter Start
            var minDate, maxDate;
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
                    var min = minDate.val();
                    var max = maxDate.val();
                    var date = new Date( data[1] );
                    if (
                        ( min === null && max === null ) ||
                        ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
                        ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
                        ( min <= date   && date <= max )
                    ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            );
            minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
                format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
            });
            maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
                format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
            });
            var editor;
           var table= $('table.table-borderless').DataTable({
            "dom":'t',
            "columnDefs": [
                            {
                                "targets": [ 1 ],
                                "visible": false,
                                "searchable": true
                            },
                            {
                                "targets": [ 0 ],
                                "visible": false,
                                "searchable": true
                            },
                            ],

            "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api();

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            amount = api
                .column( 3, { search: "applied" } )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
                amount
            );
        },
                initComplete: function() {
                    //Drop Down Account Number
                    var column = this.api().column(0);
                    var select = $('<select class="form-control" ><option value="">All Account</option></select>')
                        .appendTo($('#account_number').empty())
                        .on('change', function() {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                            column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
                            document.getElementById("account_number1").innerHTML = val;
                            //console.log(column);
                        });
                        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');

                        });
                }


            });

            //Date Filter
            $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
                table.draw();
            });


        });

    </script>
  
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.0/api/sum().js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.0/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>

</html>
```